# alignment issues btn calendar and grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vertical-alignment, alignment

Inside a panel I have an asp calendar and an asp detailsView. Im trying to get them to display along side each other but cant get the alignment correct. I would like the the calendar top left, and the detailsView top right, with the top of the grid matching the calendar.

```
<asp:Panel ID="detailsPanel" runat="server"> 
<asp:Calendar ID="calendars" VerticalAlign="top" HorizontalAlign="left" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="LoadRequestedDate_OnClick" OnDayRender="cal_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" HorizontalAlign="right" VerticalAlign="top" >
```

After table example now looks like:

[image]

Just need to align the tops
iv tried    `<td align="left">` ad right but no gd

Answer (score 0):

There are several options how to do this. I'll give you two.. one simple and one correct :)

a.) Simple: Use HTML table like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>PUT_CALENDAR_HERE</td>
    <td>PUT_DETAILS_HERE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

b.) Correct: Use CSS to modify positioning:

```
float:left; // apply this to calendar
```

Caution: You might need additional styles to tweak position. If you provide pure HTML, I could try to make a prototype in jsFiddle (otherwise I would only create it with some placeholders).
btw: You either didn't paste complete HTML, or you are missing closing tag for panel.

Edit: Here's an jsFiddle to solve your table positioning problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KdhnV/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dampe...Ive went with the table example...half way there though please see my edit for new image

Comment: yea i used <td style="vertical-align:top"> thanks again for the help